# onSharedPreferenceChanged method - Called for all activities or just current activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I was reading about `SharedPreference` in Android. I came to know that `onSharedPreferenceChanged` will be called when user changes something in the Preferences.

Consider a following code:

```
class SomeActivity extends ..
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         // Get Prefs Reference from PreferencesManager
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)
    {
        // Hit when Prefs change - Code Area - 1
    }
}
```

and say there is one more activity

```
    class SomeOtherActivity extends ..
    {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
             // Get Prefs Reference from PreferencesManager
        }

        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)
        {
            // Hit when Prefs change - Code Area - 2
        }
    }
```

Now my question is, **when user makes a changes in Preferences**:

- *would all the Activities of an Application* (`SomeActivity` and `SomeOtherActivity` in my example) would *be notified* i.e `onSharedPreferenceChanged` would be called for each activity thus hitting `Code Area - 1 and 2` both ?
- *or* it would *only* be called for a *current Activity on screen* ?

Comment: " when user makes a changes in Preferences " what 'Preferences' do you mean?

Comment: @pskink _I mean user-specific settings for an application_. The one which are represented/created using `<PreferenceScreen>` in XML.

Comment: so if you are using PreferenceActivity your current activity is...?

Comment: @pskink The activity resposible for displaying Preferences screen is say `PreferencesScreenActivity`. While there are two other activities in App - `SomeActivity` and `SomeOtherActivity`. These two activities display something based on the user preferences. Example. User Preferences has a option - _Background_. User chooses - `Blue`. Now will both the two other activities be notified about the change in Preferences (i.e. color chosen blue) or only the one that is currently active (assume currently active is 'SomeActivity')

Comment: currently active is PreferencesScreenActivity, the one that displays your preference screen

Comment: @pskink Right.. I did not pay attention to that.. Good one.. So then all would be notified about the change ? In my example both `Code Area - 1 and 2` would be hit ?

Comment: Cannot believe this. If none of the two activities is created then they will not be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should hit areas 1 and 2 both. Shared Preferences are on a per-app basis IIRC.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for more info.

Comment: In that documentation OnSharedPreferenceChanged is not even mentioned.

Comment: And what does that have to do with the problem? Or would be an answer to the problem?

Comment: He is asking whether sharedprefs apply to an application or an activity.

Comment: No. He is not asking that.

Comment: @greenapps I concluded the answer based on `pskink` and `Robin` . Do you differ in opinion ? You get me right, my question is Whether both code areas would be hit or not ? Robin concluded it indirectly by saying that since SharedPrefs apply to app, so both shud be hit. Please provide your opinion on my question.

Comment: You could already read my opinion in the other comment 'Cannot believe this...`. Please check and report.

Comment: Shared preferences apply to an app. That is true. But you were talking about two OnSharedPreferenceChanged listeners in two activities. If the activities do not exist yet then how can the listeners be invoked? I doubt they are. But why are you asking? You can test all yourself very quick. Please report.

Comment: 1-Yes, you are right. 2- I think you are missing the point of the question. 3- What does being unpleasant get you? If you wanna play semantics, my answer would be that you need to create a class that manages your app preferences, and set listeners to that class from your activities, but that was not the question.